# redirecting a pdf file to php in mod_rewrite and view the files in the same php file

Tags: php, apache, pdf, mod-rewrite

I want to block users from directly accessing pdf files in my uploads folder and only allow validated users to view the file through validate.php
validate php and the pdf files are in the same folder 
 this is my htacess file

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/pdf/
RewriteRule ^(.+\.pdf)$ validate.php?filename=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/pdf/
RewriteRule ^(.+\.pdf)$ /uploads/$1 [L]
```

Please help as i am trying from days